# slideToggle siblings others open div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to close others div if they're opened on click.

I have this code, but honestly I don't really understand, even after having been on the doc ..

I have made a fiddle [just here](https://jsfiddle.net/xgq0vve6/), but when I click on a div all hidden content is displayed.

Have an idea ?

Here is my code :

```
<div class="etape-road-trip">
    <span>Click me</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="infos-etape-road-trip">
        Hidden content
    </div>
</div>


<div class="etape-road-trip">
    <span>Click me</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="infos-etape-road-trip">
        Hidden content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

`.infos-etape-road-trip{
     display: none;
 }`

Comment: Now nothing is working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the correct content, use current element i.e. `this` and target immediately following sibling's using `.next()` child.

```
$('.etape-road-trip').click(function () {
    var currentContent = $(this).next().find('.infos-etape-road-trip');
    $('.infos-etape-road-trip').not(currentContent).slideUp();
    currentContent.slideToggle();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/xgq0vve6/1/)